# Regular expression use in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the user information from a table (named userinfo) from the Oracle database on the basis of name.

In database name can be like `{"Ashwani Dahiya","Ashwani kumar","ashwani dahiya","ashwani   kumar","Ashwani dahiya","ashwani Dahiya","ashwani"}`

So I want if I search for name "ashwani" then it should return the above whole list of users

```
select * 
from userinfo 
where regexp_like('name','Ashwani([[:space:]]* | [[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)','i')
```

I had tried this but "no result found".

Comment: are you working with oracle 10 or later ?

Comment: the literal spaces in your regex pattern will be matched against - this means that 'ashwani' will not be accepted.

Comment: Thanx collapsar I got my mistake.thanks a lot now its working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
regexp_like('name','Ashwani([[:space:]]* | [[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)','i')
```

searches inside the *string* `'name'` not inside a column called `name`. When you want to refer to a column you don't need quotes.

So you need your expression to:

```
regexp_like(name,'Ashwani([[:space:]]* | [[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)','i')
```

(Note the missing single quote `'` around `name`).

But I don't see the need for a regex here. a simple

```
where lower(name) like '%ashwani%'
```

will also do the trick (and will not be slower than the regex because neither of them will use an index)

Comment: i had tried already it without quotes .And %ashwani% will not search for case insensitive strings

Comment: @user2665433: a_horse_with_no_name's last suggestion will work because lowercased `name` is compared agaunst the lowercase pattern.

Comment: @user2665433: as collapsar said: it will work because it is compared against `lower(name)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to use the column called NAME and not the literal 'name' so try without the quotes around name and also lose the spaces around the "|":

```
select * from userinfo where regexp_like(name,'Ashwani([[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)','i')
```

Note that for testing purposes you can try it with literals like so:

```
select *
from dual
where regexp_like('ashwani ','Ashwani([[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)','i')
```

As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name, you may get away with using the "LIKE" but I'm guessing you're looking for just "ashwani" and not "ashwaniX" (where X is some other letter) in which you could have just

```
lower(name) = 'ashwani' 
or lower(name) LIKE 'ashwani %'
```

The trouble with regex functions is that they can be rather slow if you're working with a lot of data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i agree with u all but what about case sensitivity?

Comment: lower() converts all of the data to lowercase before comparison. As long as the value being compared with is also lowercase, you have a case insensitive query: start with 'AsHwAnI', lower('AsHwAnI') = 'ashwani'.

Comment: Thanx patrick,I got my mistake and  I understood your suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to cling to regexes, try

```
select * 
  from userinfo 
 where regexp_count(name, '^ashwani', 1, 'i') = 1
     ;
```

but there really is no need for if the matches will always start with the literal to compare against.